# RPC Protocols comparison

Tags: python, c, rpc, network-protocols, distributed-computing

I have to select a protocol/technology to use for communicating a client-server architecture, with support both for Python and C. The main requirements are:

1. Symmetrical communication in between ends: clients establish a connection and servers can send data back to clients through the same connection.
2. Avoid excessive overhead by using HTTP or a big stack (if possible, TCP direct communication).
3. TLS/SSL support for secure communications.
4. Ease of implementation.

For that, I evaluated the following protocols/communications technologies. I would appreciate that you could take a look at the table and tell me what you think, since most of times, it was quite hard to find the information I required for this analysis. In addition, I would also appreciate that any of you could add more protocols/technologies to the table below.

[image: Protocols Comparison]

(*1) TLS support for RPyC is based in a no-longer supported Python library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use xmlrpc, but i think ZMQ is the best choice.